# How to convert NaN values into zeroes in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, nan

I am trying to convert NaN into zeroes using Pig scripting as below but I keep getting an error message. Can someone share your thoughts on how to handle NaN's in PIG.Any insights would be appreciated. Thank you.

My input field xyz::abcd has NULL,NOT NULL,NaN values in it. Need to convert all NaN's to zeroes.

**`xyz::abcd <> 'NaN'`**

(part of my code)

Comment: What data type 'abcd' is of ? How is abcd value derived ?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to read the field as `chararray` and have a

```
 X = FOREACH xyz GENERATE (abcd == 'NaN' ? '0.0' : abcd);
```

Then you can convert your chararray to float or int or whatever.